# R list strcuture changed after splitting and i get error

Tags: r

I have the list in following structure: (its a sample)

```
dput
structure(c(-2.5671541557256, 0, 0, 0, 3.4065145441717, 
3.26323559295213, 0, 0, -3.9720219717256, -4.25576002872732, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.70164397285001, 3.98759425336171, -5.21839418370837, 
-5.22607347078334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.55820528567553, -11.845429347973, 
0, 0, 12.8723841389153, -18.0482215887575, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-2.53671223453425, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29.7594053034137, 28.3027442062031, 
0, 0, -31.8167071494086, 24.6304210515793, 0, 0, -28.6871184676624, 
22.7764979716831, -28.6587552600709, -31.7152869653583, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 59.5748909388383, 51.4308255635962, 0, 0, -48.6871743127326, 
-59.4478429661327, 0, 0), .Names = c("11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "110", "111", "112", 
"113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", 
"122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", 
"131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", 
"140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "210", "211", 
"212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", 
"221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", 
"230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", 
"239", "240", "241",))
```

after applying this code: `split(priceboot1, rep(1:500, unlist(num)))` to split the above into different chunks, the list structure becomes as follows:

```
structure(list(`1` = structure(c(-2.5671541557256, 0, 0, 0, 3.4065145441717, 
3.26323559295213, 0, 0, -3.9720219717256, -4.25576002872732, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.70164397285001, 3.98759425336171, -5.21839418370837, 
-5.22607347078334, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.55820528567553, -11.845429347973, 
0, 0, 12.8723841389153, -18.0482215887575, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Names = c("11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", 
"116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", 
"125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", 
"134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", 
"143", "144", "145", "146", "147")), `2` = structure(c(-2.53671223453425, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29.7594053034137, 28.3027442062031, 
0, 0, -31.8167071494086, 24.6304210515793, 0, 0, -28.6871184676624, 
22.7764979716831, -28.6587552600709, -31.7152869653583, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 59.5748909388383, 51.4308255635962, 0, 0, -48.6871743127326, 
-59.4478429661327, 0, 0), .Names = c("21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", 
"215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", 
"224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", 
"233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241"
)),
```

And then later when I try this code on similar list structure: `getinvbootnum<-lapply(finalfinalpriceboot, FUN=function(x) seq(1,length(x),by=2))` i get the error `Error in seq.default(1, length(x), by = 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`

is this because of the change in the list structure or something else completely? please help.

Comment: What is split(priceboot1, rep(1:500, unlist(num)))  ?  What is priceboot, and what is num?

Comment: `split` is designed to split on `f`, which is "a ‘factor’ in the sense that as.factor(f) defines the grouping", maybe you want `cut`

Comment: Error in seq.default(1, length(x), by = 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument - Looks like one of the sublists have zero size. Do lappy(finalfinalpriceboot, length) to see which one

Comment: There's something wrong with your `dput()`s. Please make sure you include the complete code for them.

Comment: @AlexJoseph Yes that is exactly what is happening. How do I make it such that it ignores the 0?

Comment: @Hack-R I have edited the dput(). sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the sublists have zero size.e

Change

```
apply(finalfinalpriceboot, FUN=function(x) seq(1,length(x),by=2))
```

to

```
apply(finalfinalpriceboot[sapply(finalfinalpriceboot, length) > 0], FUN=function(x) seq(1,length(x),by=2))
```

Will make it apply the function only on the elements of the list longer with a >0 length